# Need to write arithmetic progression using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, math

I need to write an arithmetic progression using recursion with first value(a1) = 2, difference(d) = 3, and there will be 15 members(n) at all in C++. I've written, but it doesn't work(

```
int progressionRec(int a1, int d, int n){
    if(n == 1){
        return a1;
    }
    else
        return a1+d*progressionRec(a1, d, n - 1);

}
```

I need the output: 44 41 38 ... 2, but it gives me: 14348906 ...

Comment: The code you’ve shown doesn’t produce any output, so it’s impossible to say why it shows what you describe instead of what you want.

Comment: Edit the question to show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to ouput multiple numbers but can only return 1 integer value from a function, therefore just print the numbers and dont return them if that is an option.

here:

```
void progressionRec(int a1, int d, int n) {
    if(n <= 1){
        printf("%d\n", a1);
        return;
    } else {
        int next = a1 + d;
        printf("%d\n", a1);
        progressionRec(next, d, n - 1);
    }
}
```

if you want it to go downwards like 44, 41, 38..
just pass a negative value to the paramter 'd'

for example:

```
progressionRec(44, -3, 10);
```

Comment: put the printf line below progressionRecv line to flip the output order

Comment: no they should not be together, recopy the function please i have tested it

Comment: Thank u, it really works now, and how can i count the sum of this progression?

Comment: you will need another function, you can do it without recursion with basic math though

Comment: but if i need it in recursion way?

Comment: that is another question, my friend

Answer (score 0):

Using your original code, it should read

```
int progressionRec(int a1, int d, int n){
    if(n == 1){
        return a1;
}
    else
        return progressionRec(a1, d, n - 1) + d;
}
```

This returns a single value, the nth element of the series.
However you state that you want the results in reverse order [a1+(n-1)d],[a1+(n-2)d], ... a1 . This can be done by calling the function from within a loop with a decreasing index used as 'n'. Like the previous answer, do you want to print each term from within the function or to have it return successive results from repeated calls?